# CorelDRAW row number

Tags: corel-draw, tables, numbering

Can someone help me with this problem in CorelDRAW?

I have a table with 16 rows (2 pages, left and right because of the binding), and I need to insert  on the first column on each row a number starting from 2874 on first page (e.g. 2874, 2875 ...2889-last row on first page) and counting until page 100.

The only solution I know is to make the numbers in Excel (this way I don't have to type all 1600 number for each row) and copy them back to CorelDRAW, but it's still a hassle to arrange them on every page.

Comment: Why not do that in indesign? I believe it would be the proper tool for this type of job

Comment: it would be you are right but the original file was made in corel draw :( (and i don't know that much indesign to draw tables and that good stuff that he would be much better than corel draw)

Comment: Have you tried googling for a solution? there must be a macro somewhere in a Corel Draw forum...

Comment: i did and can't find anything or i don't know how to search

Comment: this is what i am trying to achieve https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7mc527gku3thhe/InDesign_2019-03-12_10-36-42.png?dl=0
 but it still takes a lot to edit the first number from the first row for every page
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qv005kn4mnjznud/2019-03-12_10-40-15.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to just post this CorelDRAW forum link as a comment, but I don't have enough rep:

[Any Faster Way to Auto-Numbering Columns & Rows on One page Only?](https://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_x6/f/coreldraw-x6/37576/any-faster-way-to-auto-numbering-columns-rows-on-one-page-only)

The macro (`BDTableTextControl_v2.gms`) posted by Brian in that thread gets close to  achieving what you're looking to do.

To make this more like a legitimate answer, here are the steps I took to install, run, and use the macro:

1. Save the macro file to your desired location on your desktop (right-click → Save As).
   (I just left it in my Downloads folder as I couldn't get it to work from the
   "correct" `AppData` folder.)
2. Open the Macro Manager (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or Tools → Macros **>** Macro Manager).
3. Click Load and select the `BDTableTextControl_v2.gms` file.  The macro should now appear in the Visual Basic for Applications tree within the Macro Manager.
4. Double-click BDTableTextControl from the Macro Manager to run the macro.

   [image]
5. In the macro dialog, set your desired starting number.

   [image]
6. In the table, select the cells where you want the numbers to appear
   [image]
7. Click the "Add Numbers" button.
   [image]

Unfortunately, it's not an automated thing, so you'll likely have to run the macro again for each of your 100 pages, but at least it's not having to hand type each number on every row.  Hope this helps.